# Java ORM framework that supports i18n out of the box?

Tags: java, orm, internationalization

Is there a java orm framework, or an extension to one, that supports i18n out of the box?

I found [jpa-translator](https://code.google.com/p/jpa-translator/) which pretty much looks to be exactly what I am looking for, but it has not been updated since 2009. But my vision of what I want i similar. You mark the fields that should be able to be translated with a `@Translate` annotation or something similar and the framework takes care of the rest (class/field/sql-generation), whether it is through code generation or during runtime...

Answer (score 0):

i18n is better done on the application level after your orm of choice(or plain sql) retrieves the data.
you could create your own @Translate interface that takes a key and when the get method is called it would try to retrieve a translation of it using the key (and Locale).

If your already using any kind of framework (is it a wep app? desktop?) then it probably has a i18n mechanism or offers suggestions on how to do i18n.

Comment: I just thought that this would be such a common need that there would be some solution ready for it so that I can focus on business logic. I am using hibernate which I am fairly new to.